# Is it technically possible to display a list of 500 thousand of images on a recyclerview + paging?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Correct me if I am wrong. RecyclerView just helps us with efficiently displaying a large list by just displaying the items on the list that are available to the viewport of the user right? and paging just helps us load data by chunks? as we scroll down farder we are allocating more and more objects to the memory (paging) so is it technically possible to display a size of example a 500 thousands of image on recyclerview?

Comment: It does not matter how much you have in the basement as at any time your app would only need the ones that are visible. 10? 20? You only have to store them on your device. Or load from internet or cloud when needed.

Comment: so we need to remove the first loaded 20 then we load 20 again is that what you are implying ? because If I understand correctly paging does not remove the first loaded items it just adds up data as we scroll there fore allocating more memory as the use scroll

Comment: You can't just ignore paging, if that's what you're asking. Where are you getting these 500,000 image Urls from? If it's an in-memory list, that's going to take up a lot of memory. If it's from an API (more likely), that's a huge API call.

Comment: that 500k images are just an example I am learning how to scale my app here. the 500k image is being paged from my api i loaded 50 image per page. So the response of the api must be stored in an a list of object eg. List<PhotoData> so that has to be allocated in the memory. as the user scrolls the app would have to allocated PhotoData() * total of paged photos so as the user scrolls the memory usage would pile up. So is it possible then? no right?

Comment: The Paging Library solves the problem you're mentioning by allowing you to only load a small subset of the data into memory at any given time. You certainly could do it the way you're describing, and it's probably just fine to do it that way while you're learning. It's just not going to perform quite as well. But paging is an advanced topic, so don't feel like you need to learn it immediately.

Comment: I see paging has drop page functionality by setting maxSize thank you. so technically its possible to display the photo list of 500k image?

Comment: `so we need to remove the first loaded 20 then we load 20 again is that what you are implying ?` Remove from where? A recycleview will only use about twenty items hence twenty images. They got recycled. You have to do nothing for that. You will only load and display an image if it has to be visible like only when you scroll to it.

Comment: remove from the List<Items> where the recyclerview is reading